# How to create sub bullet points (nested bullet points under bullet points) using Google Slides API

Tags: google-slides, google-slides-api

I'm trying to use the Google Slides API to create nested bullet points within a paragraph. Currently, I'm able to create a paragraph with bullet points, but I'm struggling to create sub-bullet points (nested bullet points) under existing bullet points.

Here's the current request body I'm using:

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "createParagraphBullets": {
        "objectId": "i0",
        "textRange": {
          "type": "ALL"
        },
        "bulletPreset": "BULLET_DISC_CIRCLE_SQUARE"
      }
    },
    {
      "createParagraphBullets": {
        "objectId": "i0",
        "textRange": {
          "type": "ALL"
        },
        "bulletPreset": "BULLET_DISC_CIRCLE_SQUARE"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I modify the above code to create sub bullet points (nested bullet points) under the bullet points created by the first request using the Google Slides API? I tried nestingLevel suggested by ChatGPT but no luck!

ChatGPT result:

```json
{
    "requests": [
      {
        "createParagraphBullets": {
          "objectId": "i0",
          "textRange": {
            "type": "ALL"
          },
          "bulletPreset": "BULLET_DISC_CIRCLE_SQUARE"
        }
      },
      {
        "createParagraphBullets": {
          "objectId": "i0",
          "textRange": {
            "type": "ALL"
          },
          "bulletPreset": "BULLET_DISC_CIRCLE_SQUARE",
          "nestingLevel": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

---

[sample image of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm3dg.png)

Comment: I refined my query, hope its clear now!

Comment: Actually I couldn't find any way to create nested/sub bullet points in google slides API docs, I am searching for solution that worked for anyone. 

Currently I am mimicking sub bullet points in this way but its not the proper way:
```
 {
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "objectId": "i0",
        "text": "bullet point 1\n\t•\tNested bullet point",
        "insertionIndex": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a nest list in a text box on Google Slides.
- You want to achieve this using "Method: presentations.batchUpdate" of Google Slides API.

In this case, how about the following request body? Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand your input situation. So, in this answer, the request body also includes creating a text box and the texts.

#### Sample request body:

To create the nest list, the tab `\t` is used in the inserting text. And also, at `createParagraphBullets`, `"type": "ALL"` is used. By this, the nest structure is automatically created using `\t`.

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "createShape": {
        "shapeType": "RECTANGLE",
        "elementProperties": {
          "size": {
            "height": {
              "unit": "PT",
              "magnitude": 200
            },
            "width": {
              "unit": "PT",
              "magnitude": 200
            }
          },
          "pageObjectId": "###"  // <--- Please set your page object ID.
        },
        "objectId": "abc123456"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "text": "sample1\n\tsample2\n\t\tsample3",
        "objectId": "abc123456"
      }
    },
    {
      "createParagraphBullets": {
        "bulletPreset": "BULLET_DISC_CIRCLE_SQUARE",
        "objectId": "abc123456",
        "textRange": {
          "type": "ALL"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The sample curl command using this request body is as follows.

```bash
curl --request POST \
  'https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/{googleSlideId}:batchUpdate' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"requests":[{"createShape":{"shapeType":"RECTANGLE","elementProperties":{"size":{"height":{"unit":"PT","magnitude":200},"width":{"unit":"PT","magnitude":200}},"pageObjectId":"###"},"objectId":"abc123456"}},{"insertText":{"text":"sample1\n\tsample2\n\t\tsample3","objectId":"abc123456"}},{"createParagraphBullets":{"bulletPreset":"BULLET_DISC_CIRCLE_SQUARE","objectId":"abc123456","textRange":{"type":"ALL"}}}]}' \
  --compressed
```

#### Testing:

When the above request body is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [CreateParagraphBulletsRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createparagraphbulletsrequest)